# Arrivano ben prima di mezzanotte - meaning

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, difference

I have read the following sentence in an Italian learning tool:

> Arrivano ben prima di mezzanotte.
>   (= They arrive well before midnight)

Does that mean that they will arrive well or that they will arrive much earlier than midnight? Given the context and that the sentence refers to the future, I believe that the intended meaning is the latter. However, if the sentence was in the past, the intended meaning would be harder to grasp (eg Sono arrivati ben prima di mezzanotte). Maybe a comma would make a difference ?

Comment: _Arrivano_ would be _they arrive_, _arriviamo_ would be _we arrive_.

Comment: Right. Fixed it

Comment: The elision of _bene_, in itself, denotes that the word connects to _prima_. You wouldn't say _sono arrivati ben_ to say that they are “well arrived” (and even _sono arrivati bene_ sounds somewhat unusual).

Comment: @DaG I agree with you about the elision, but inserting the comma the meaning could become ambiguous, and that's what the OP qas questioning. Moreover saying _Sono arrivati bene_ you would mean with no troble at all, _senza alcun problema_.

Comment: @DaG, Thanks for making clear that "ben" would be "bene" if it didn't refer to "prima"and that that is already enough to infer the meaning of the sentence. Nevertheless, I assume that the comma in "Sono arrivati bene, prima di mezzanotte" is obligatory if the intended meaning is "We arrived well AND we arrived before midnight" ?

Comment: @abarisone To make it clear, my main question is how to differentiate the two possible meanings of the sentence. Using a comma was only a suggestion. I think that your statement "inserting the comma, the meaning could become ambiguous" is confusing. Adding a comma to this sentence as I suggested *removes* any ambiguity instead of *introducing* it.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Better rewrite my comment: _inserting the comma, the meaning consistently changes_

Comment: The whole sentence isn't actually completely natural. What would you mean by _sono arrivati bene_? They were safe and sound when they arrived, something like that? If so, you'd probably say, as Abarisone says, _sono arrivati senza problemi (prima di mezzanotte)_ or the like. The comma isn't compulsory, but probably most people would insert it, for clarity's sake.

Comment: @DaG yes, I understand "arrivare bene" as "to arrive safe and sound".

Comment: Not sure most people would use it like this. It sounds strange to me, and a quick Google search shows mostly sport news, where _arrivare bene_ means most of the times something like “arrive at some competition (_al mondiale, al derby, al campionato_...) in good shape”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the meaning without punctuation would be the latter, they will arrive much earlier than midnight.

If the sentence was in the past you would have these two cases, using a comma:

> Sono arrivati, ben prima di mezzanotte (they will arrive much earlier than midnight)

and the other case where *ben* becomes *bene*, since the apocope wouldn't sound natural.

> Sono arrivati bene, prima di mezzanotte (they arrived well, before midgnight)

So the usage of a simple comma would make a difference in meaning.